# Give a one-to-one and onto function from $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Give a function $g : \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$

such that $g$ is one-to-one and onto function.

the onto part I could easily solve but every function I think of, is not one-to-one.

Comment: Here's a one-to-one function from $\{1,2,3,\ldots\}\times\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ to $\{1,2,3,\ldots\}{:}$
$$
\begin{array}{c|cccccccccc}
& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & \cdots \\
\hline
1 & 1 & 2 & 4 & 7 & 11 & 16 & 22 \\
2 & 3 & 5 & 8 & 12 & 17 & 23 \\
3 & 6 & 9 & 13 & 18 & 24 \\
4 & 10 & 14 & 19 & 25 \\
5 & 15 & 20 & 26 \\
6 & 21 & 27 \\
7 & 28 \\
\vdots
\end{array}
$$
If the pattern is not clear, consider this: $\qquad$

Comment: If the pattern is not clear, consider this:
$$
\begin{array}{c|cccccccccc}
& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & \cdots \\
\hline
1 & & & & & & & 22 \\
2 & & & & & & 23 \\
3 & & & & & 24 \\
4 & & & & 25 \\
5 & & & 26 \\
6 & & 27 \\
7 & 28 \\
\vdots
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two standard examples:
$$(x,y)\mapsto y+\frac{(x+y)(x+y+1)}{2},$$
it is [technical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function) to prove it is a bijection and not too interesting.

The other one is given by:
$$(x,y)\mapsto 2^x(2y+1)-1,$$
it is bijective essentially from the [fundamental theorem of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic).

Comment: @asdf Who said anything about positive integers?

Comment: My comment was regarding @Ahmad's comment since my definition of $\mathbb{N}$ excludes $0$